# Regexp to search for phrase containing other phrase and don't mark anything other

Tags: regex, notepad++

Similar topics appear here quite frequently but even analyzing them i still can't figure the proper regexp to do my task. I have an XML file with some sections. I need to remove text sections which contain given attributes and leave the everything else.

The example text section:

```
<Text FontFamily="Open Sans" FontSize="19" FontStyle="Normal"
    FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalAlign="Left" Left="803.0"
    Name="Back" Stroke="#CCCCCC" TextDecoration="None"
    Top="126.0" Visibility="Hidden">
... More content here ...
</Text>
```

I need to find and remove only the ones containing `Name="Back"`. There are different `Name` attributes in other text sections or there are sections without `Name` at all (not named). Sections are multilined.

The simplest regexp is:

```
(?s)<Text (.*?)Name="Back"(.*?)</Text>
```

and also an improper one. If `Name="Back"` appears then regexp marks the proper part. But if this special phrase is not there, then it starts from
`<Text>` then marks many other text or not text sections until it finds 
`</Text>` followed by `Name="Back"` which can be at end of file. So it marks almost the whole file, many texts and not text sections.

There is no point in showing my other regexp trials I tried to create based on other people's regexp solutions. The final regexp marks nothing or marks too much.

I will be grateful for help.

By the way, how do I escape `<` here? `<` plus `Text` won't appear in text, only in the code segment.

Comment: 1. Do you have to do this with regex and notepad++? Because you probably should just use an XML parsing library 2. Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for angle brackets in SO posts

Comment: No, rather in notepad++. Is it impossible to do this in npp?

Comment: Formatting `<` and any other code should be done with backticks, either triple fences for large blocks or single backticks (`) for inline snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, try this:

```
(?s)<Text[^>]*? Name="Back".*?>.*?<\/Text>
```

See the demo at https://regex101.com/r/Dmyq59/1

^ I know it's not Notepad++ but they're both PCRE

---

If you paste your regex into my regex101 example then it will visualize the problem for you which is `Text (.*?)Name="Back"` because `(.*?)` will continue capturing EVERYTHING until it reaches a tag which does contain `Name="Back"`

---

You should strongly consider installing the XPatherizerNPP plugin so that you can use XPath. The equivalent XPath would have been `//text[@name='Back']`

Comment: Seems to be working. It works without >.*? but i understand that it is additional condition to check. How to exclude more than > like in [^>]? I tried to use (?!Text) earlier but it didn't work.

Comment: @KrzysztofJachowicz Certainly, sometimes I prefer expressiveness over brevity especially when `(?s)` is involved; it can screw up your whole day if not careful. Additionally, consider installing the XPatherizerNPP plugin so that you can use XPath. The equivalent XPath would have been `//text[@name='Back']`

Comment: @KrzysztofJachowicz I don't know what you mean by "How to exclude more than `>`". `[^]` is a negated char set so you can add multiple chars to it.

Comment: You have used [^>] to specify condition where > won't appear before Name="Back". Is there a way to specify that Stroke word instead of > can't appear before? [^Stroke] won't work, each characters will be treated separately. Negative look ahead (?!Stroke) is also not working but i have seen similar examples using such construction.

Comment: @KrzysztofJachowicz Are you requesting that `Stroke` specifically cannot appear before `Name="Back"` or that you wish to ignore all `<text>` which contain `Stroke` regardless of its position inside of `<text>`? How would you phrase the rule? Would it be "Find `<text>` which contains `name="back"` and no `Stroke`"? Regardless, XPath is going to be much more simpler.

Comment: @KrzysztofJachowicz XPath would simply be `//text[@name='Back' and not(@stroke)]`

Comment: No. To be clear Your solution worked perfectly, but i had similar cases where I needed to exclude not a certain character but whole word. I have found that ((?!Stroke).)* is working for me to exclude word.

Comment: @KrzysztofJachowicz So you want to select all `<text>` nodes which do not contain the `Stroke` attribute?

Comment: It is OK now. The Visibility was next attribute to exclude so i modified it to: 
(?s)\n\s+<Text [^>]*? Name="Back"[^>]*? Visibility="Hidden".*?>.*?<\/Text>

Comment: @KrzysztofJachowicz Great, but I still recommend XPath at the end of the day. `//text[@name='Back' and @visibility='Hidden"]` since it doesn't care about the ordering of attributes.